# sql/php - add 4 days to unixtimestamps, with different starting days

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I have a database with 30k+ users. I wish to add 4 days to a time I have stored for each user in unixtimestamp.

The time represent when they have joined, therefore each timestamp is different than the other.

Can I, simply, add 4 days to ALL of these timestamp via. SQL?

Comment: Just sum up 60*60*24 seconds, to current unixtimestamp!

`UPDATE table set start_date = start_date + 60*60*24`

Comment: @Michael, day is longer then 60*60*24 ( leap year and related stuff)

Comment: @MichaelLivach why do you think so? There's no difference in day time seconds, i just forgot to add multiplier by 4 days!

Comment: @Michael, I definitely encountered complications with dates and timestamps manipulation, but can't remember reasons for now, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can

```
UPDATE yourtable SET yourfield = yourfield + 345600
```

or you calculate it directly in your query.

```
UPDATE yourtable SET yourfield = yourfield + (60*60*24*4)
```

But you should make some tests before.

Answer (score 1):

Try with INTERVAL 4 DAYS like this

```
UPDATE tbl_name set time_col = DATE_ADD(time_col, INTERVAL 4 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do it using single `UPDATE` query. Try this

```
UPDATE `users` SET time = time+(86400*4);
```